# How to store output in log file in this case:

Tags: bash, shell, curl, webhooks, logfile

```
webhook=https://webhook-url

if [[ some_condition ]]; then
curl "some_command..." -d '{"content":"'"success"'"}' $webhook #sends message to discord if condition is met
else
curl "some_command..." -d '{"content":"'"error"'"}' $webhook #sends message to discord if condition isn't met
fi
```

Above bash script successfully sends message to discord but at the same time I want it to store the same message in a log file. Without using webhook, earlier code was as follows:

```
if [[ some_condition ]]; then
echo "success" >> file.log
else
echo "error" >> file.log
fi
```

Now I'm not sure how do I include `>> file.log` command in first script.

Comment: Please add your desired content of file.log to your question (no comment here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just merge the contents of the if block from the two scripts:

```
if [[ some_condition ]]; then
    message="Some 'success' information."
    curl "some_command..." -d '{"content":"$message"}' $webhook #sends message to discord if condition is met
    echo $message >> file.log
else
    message="Some 'error' information."
    curl "some_command..." -d '{"content":"$message"}' $webhook #sends message to discord if condition isn't met
    echo $message >> file.log
fi
```

Comment: This works, thanks, but is there a way that the message after `"content"` can be sent to log file? I mean if instead of **success**, there's a long message, send it to file.log instead of writing entire message in echo again.

Comment: @Learner This sounds like rather trivial scripting. Perhaps you should consider some basic tutorial? In any case I updated my answer for the new scope-creep.

Answer (score 1):

If the content being sent to discord is just "success"

Shouldn't you just be able to do this?

```
webhook=https://webhook-url

if [[ some_condition ]]; then
curl "some_command..." -d '{"content":"'"success"'"}' $webhook
echo "success" >> file.log
else
curl "some_command..." -d '{"content":"'"error"'"}' $webhook 
echo "error" >> file.log
fi
```

Otherwise, if you are trying to store the response from curl, perhaps something like this could work?

```
webhook=https://webhook-url

if [[ some_condition ]]; then
res=$(curl "some_command..." -d '{"content":"'"success"'"}' $webhook)
echo "$res" >> file.log
else
res=$(curl "some_command..." -d '{"content":"'"error"'"}' $webhook)
echo "$res" >> file.log
fi
```

Update:

Maybe try this?

```
cmd="curl "some_command..." -d '{"content":"'"success"'"}' $webhook"
echo $cmd >> file.log
```

Comment: First solution works, thanks but second one doesn't send response to log file. Basically I'm using curl command for the discord webhook, so I only need to send what is after `"content"`. I mean if instead of **success**, there's a long message, is it possible to send it to file.log instead of writing entire message in echo again. It's pretty much what your second solution is doing but it's not working.

Comment: Let me know if the update in my comment works...

Comment: success message had to be defined outside like `cmd="success"` and then `'{"content":"'"$cmd"'"}'`. Then it works.